# WordPress Navwalker not toggling open on mobile

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming

I have implemented the WP_navwalker in my project but it will not open on mobile. I will post the code below. If I miss something please let me know. I appreciate it if someone can help me find out what I might be missing. Thank you.

I am using the latest navwalker from https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker
and have followed various tutorials to the letter but just can't seem to get the button toggle to open the menu. Again, Thank you for your help on this.

[image]

functions.php

```
/**
 * Register Custom Navigation Walker
 */
function register_navwalker(){
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' );

register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'rrspark' ),
) );



 function html5blank_header_scripts()
{
    if ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' && !is_admin()) {

        wp_register_script('conditionizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/conditionizr-4.3.0.min.js', array(), '4.3.0'); // Conditionizr
        wp_enqueue_script('conditionizr'); // Enqueue it!

        wp_register_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js', array(), '2.7.1'); // Modernizr
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr'); // Enqueue it!

        wp_register_script('html5blankscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('html5blankscripts'); // Enqueue it!
    }
}

// Load HTML5 Blank conditional scripts
function html5blank_conditional_scripts()
{
    if (is_page('pagenamehere')) {
        wp_register_script('scriptname', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scriptname.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Conditional script(s)
        wp_enqueue_script('scriptname'); // Enqueue it!
    }
}

// Load HTML5 Blank styles
function html5blank_styles()
{
    wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('html5blank', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('html5blank'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('montserrat', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('montserrat'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('kaushan', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('kaushan'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('droid', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('droid'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('roboto', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('roboto'); // Enqueue it!

    // wp_register_style('agencystyles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/agency.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    // wp_enqueue_style('agencystyles'); 

    wp_register_style('customstyles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('customstyles'); 
    // Enqueue it!

}
```

header.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark navbar-expand-md fixed-top" id="mainNav" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <a href="/rrspark">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/homelogo.png" alt="home-brand-logo" style="width: 125px;">
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
            ) );
            ?>
        </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

before closing body tag in footer.php

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?> . /js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Edit, made changes to the functions.php

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    Functions
\*------------------------------------*/

/**
 * Register Custom Navigation Walker
 */
function register_navwalker(){
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' );

register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'rrspark' ),
) );


// Load HTML5 Blank scripts (header.php)
function html5blank_header_scripts() {
    if ( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' && ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( HTML5_DEBUG ) {
            // jQuery
            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/jquery.js', array(), '1.11.1' );

            // Conditionizr
            wp_register_script( 'conditionizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/conditionizr-4.3.0.min.js', array(), '4.3.0' );

            // Modernizr
            wp_register_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/modernizr.js', array(), '2.8.3' );

            // Custom scripts
            wp_register_script(
                'html5blankscripts',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js',
                array(
                    'conditionizr',
                    'modernizr',
                    'jquery'
                ),
                '1.0.0' );

            // Enqueue Scripts
            wp_enqueue_script( 'html5blankscripts' );

        // If production
        } else {
            // Scripts minify
            wp_register_script( 'html5blankscripts-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array(), '1.0.0' );
            // Enqueue Scripts
            wp_enqueue_script( 'html5blankscripts-min' );
        }
    }
}



// Load HTML5 Blank conditional scripts
function html5blank_conditional_scripts()
{
    if (is_page('pagenamehere')) {
        wp_register_script('scriptname', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scriptname.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Conditional script(s)
        wp_enqueue_script('scriptname'); // Enqueue it!
    }
}

// Load HTML5 Blank styles
function html5blank_styles()
{
    wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('html5blank', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('html5blank'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('montserrat', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('montserrat'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('kaushan', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('kaushan'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('droid', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('droid'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('roboto', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('roboto'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('customstyles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('customstyles'); 
    // Enqueue it!

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_enqueue_awesome' );
/**
 * Register and load font awesome CSS files using a CDN.
 */
function prefix_enqueue_awesome() {
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome-5', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.0/css/all.css', array(), '5.3.0');
}

// Register HTML5 Blank Navigation
function register_html5_menu()
{
    register_nav_menus(array( // Using array to specify more menus if needed
        'header-menu' => __('Header Menu', 'html5blank'), // Main Navigation
        'sidebar-menu' => __('Sidebar Menu', 'html5blank'), // Sidebar Navigation
        'extra-menu' => __('Extra Menu', 'html5blank') // Extra Navigation if needed (duplicate as many as you need!)
    ));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_load_bootstrap' );
/**
 * Enqueue Bootstrap.
 */
function custom_load_bootstrap() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );
}
```

Second Edit showing dev tools output

[image: Header output]

[image: Footer Output]

After removing the extra div that was pointed out to me, I got the nav bar to expand. The problem is that the navbar opens on mobile by default and doesn't close. Please see image.
[image: open nav]

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Also I recommend using `wp_enqueue_script` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) for bootstrap and jQuery.  jQuery might already be loaded looking at `html5blankscripts`...

Comment: No console errors. I have made some adjustments to the code but still no-go. I will make an edit in a few minutes. I have enqueue'd the scripts and still no luck.

Comment: Can you post the output from `wp_nav_menu`?

Comment: Confirmed all scripts and styles are loaded on the front end?

Comment: I have added new images showing the dev tools outputs for both header and footer. I am not sure how to output the wp_nav_menu but if you tell me how, I can do that quickly.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra div `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">`. Im not seeing that in the examples for the Bootstrap Walker Plugin.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Now the nav toggles open on mobile and won't close. I traded one issue for another hahaha.